# My rails app let user vote on posts, how to make user see "unvoted by his own" posts at index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app has simple user/post/vote structure, user can up-vote/down-vote on each post. I want to let user to see "their own unvoted posts" at the index page, I tried `where` `where.not` but can't combine it to work.

I tried to do this in the `posts_controller` and my best try is to find all unvoted posts but don't know how to get related to users.

```
def index
if logged_in?
  @posts = Post.where.not(id: Vote.all.map(&:voteable_id))
else
  @posts = Post.all.sort_by{|x| x.total_votes}.reverse
end
```

end

The vote is polymorphic association, below are the 3 models:

```
Post: has_many :votes, as: :voteable, 
Vote: belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true, 
User: has_many :votes
```

I have `logged_in?` to judge if `@current_user` exists.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/Tim-Feng/ad-judge

Comment: How does user relate to votes? Show your model association code, and it may be a little easier to help you update your queries.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPeters, I use polymorphic association on vote model, below are the 3 models: `Post: has_many :votes, as: :voteable`, `Vote: belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true`, `User: has_many :votes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "their own unvoted posts" since the example code you have is kind of confusing.

If you need to find the current user's posts which have no votes you should do the following:

```
current_user.posts.where.not(id: Vote.pluck(:voteable_id).uniq)
```

If on the other hand you need to find the posts that have not been voted by the current user, you should be using only the current user's votes like so:

```
Post.where.not(id: current_user.votes.pluck(:voteable_id).uniq)
```

Hope it helps

*TIP*: if you need to make your code more efficient you can make it run all in one query by using left joins instead of searching for the ids to except.

Comment: it's the 2nd one and it works! sorry for my confusing code. And for the tip, I don't know what left joins is but I will find ti out. Thanks!